# Old family patents

Tags: ownership, patentownership

My grandfather had 5 patents related to bottle design. They have since expired. What happens to those patents?  Is there anyway I can renew them, purchase them, something. I know nothing about patents.

Darrell E. Briner
Casket Handling Apparatus 
Bottle
Flask
Whiskey Flask
Jar

He worked for Anchor Hocking, Indiana Glass and a few other glass companies in the country. He lived in Winchester, Indiana.

Answer (score 2):

The deal with patents is that you trade exclusivity for a certain amount of time (20 yrs from filing now, 17yrs from grant then) versus the publication of your invention.

After the patent expires, the invention becomes free for anyone.

Therefore, there is no way to renew the patents. They have lapsed and now are only of sentimental value.

Comment: Back then utility patents expired 17 years from the grant date. Of the 5 patents, one was a utility patent and the others were design patents.

Comment: @EricShain good point

Answer (score 1):

DonQuiKong’s answer is correct. In addition, I’d like to point out that all of the patents were assigned to companies which means that although your grandfather was listed as an inventor, he didn’t “own” the patents.

One thing you can do is to download pdf’s from patents.google.com. I know some inventors frame the patent cover page. If you want to get fancy, there are companies that make nice patent plaques (for a price).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Disappointing as it may be, the fact that I found patents that my mother knew nothing about, was exciting. I will print them all and make a great collage. I have some of his actual bottles that he made, as well. He was a mold maker, by trade. Many of the commerative bottles, made in the 60's and 70's were his design. No mention of him, we just know his mold. Thank you again.

Comment: @BeverleeKaster I have some patents and hope some day my grandkids find out about them. (I guess I need grandchildren first)

Comment: Are there any restrictions with the printouts? Would it be alright to put them on T-shirts?

Comment: @BeverleeKaster well technically there is probably copyright on them. Personally, I don't think anyone would care.

Comment: @BeverleeKaster  Copyright questions are best addressed in the Law SE site. I agree with DonQuiKong as I can’t imagine any one caring especially if you aren’t selling the T-shirts.